# Query results that not are in previous query result

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I want to retrieve from my table the `id_product` of the products which haven't got some `attribute` and it's `value` is not the ones i want

For example i want the id_product of the products in which `attribute = 'Product Type'` and `value != 'Motherboard' AND value != 'Intel Motherboard'`

I have the following table:
Atr_basic

```
column         | type                 | attributes
---------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
id             | int                  | (identity) primary key
attribute      | varchar              | not null
value          | varchar              | not null
category       | int                  | not null  
id_product     | int                  | not null
```

The query:

```
SELECT id_product 
FROM Atr_basic 
WHERE attribute = 'Product Type' 
      AND value != 'Motherboard' AND value != 'Intel Motherboard' AND category = 140
```

The problem with this query it's only give me the `id_product` from the products they have `Attribute = 'Product Type'` but some product doesn't have `Attribute = 'Product Type'`

I managed to do this query but it takes 120seconds to complete:

```
SELECT id_product 
FROM Atr_basic as ab
WHERE id_product 
    NOT IN (SELECT a.id_product 
                   FROM Atr_basic as a
                   WHERE a.attribute = 'Product Type' 
                   AND a.value != 'Motherboard' 
                   AND a.value != 'Intel Motherboard' 
                   AND Category = 140)
```

Comment: I think you need indexes on attribute, value and category columns

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the single quote closure after motherboard in both of your queries

AND value != 'Motherboard AND

AND a.value != 'Motherboard

The first query can be more organized as

```
SELECT id_product 
FROM Atr_basic 
WHERE attribute = 'Product Type' 
AND category = 140
AND value NOT IN ( 'Motherboard', 'Intel Motherboard')
```

Comment: Compound `INDEX(attribute, category)` will help performance.  Getting rid of the `IN(SELECT...)` led to the huge speedup.